# jquery add remove input fields

Tags: jquery

Hello i have the following code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf6tT/). The add function works ok but the remove function doesn't work at all. Can you help me please solve the problem?

HTLM Part

### Add Another Input Box

```
<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Jquery Part:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problem with `$('#remScnt').on('click', function() {` is that you're trying to bind the event handler to the elements in the `$('#remScnt')` collection, which is empty at that time.

Another problem is that only one element can have a given id, so you must use a class if you want to be able to add more than one line.

So I recommend this construct :

```
    $('<p><label [...] class="remScnt"   [...]  ').appendTo(scntDiv);

    ...

    $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/35tsH/)

Comment: +1 although an explanation could be in place, and a context closer than `document` could easily be picked given the code in the question.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I fixed the context. I'll write a more detailled explanation.

Comment: @dystroy your code doesn't work. You need to bind to body. Your demonstration has correct code :)

Comment: @BasaratAli I just tested it with this selector, it works for me.

Comment: works for me as well. There was a disconnect between the demonstration and code sample. I see you've fixed it now. +1

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to an element before it is created. You need to do live monitoring:

```
 $(document).on('click','#remScnt' ,function() {
```

Working fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/gnQzk/

That said, I recommend using a class instead of id.

ie. something like :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
```

Comment: It's illegal to give the same id to more than one element.

Comment: Yeah I was mentioning that :)

Comment: it's just some fast code ... i need to do .. for our secretary to work make some internal invoices that we use. and i knew it was something like that ( read the manual ) but i wasn't sure about the implementation of delegated events.